# Flask. Контекст приложения. Хранение глобальных переменных

Tags: python, flask

Как правильно хранить глобальные переменные в приложении Flask?

Использую flask.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from flask import Flask, send_file, g

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return send_file(os.path.join(get_folder(), 'index.html'),
                     attachment_filename='index.html')

def run(conn_, folder_):
    print(folder_)
    with app.app_context():
        g.conn = conn_
        g.folder = folder_

        print(g.folder)

    with app.app_context():
        print(g.get('folder'))

    app.run()

def get_folder():
    with app.app_context():
        return g.folder

# @app.teardown_appcontext
# def teardown_folder():
#     with app.app_context():
#         folder = g.pop('folder', None)
```

При вызове метода run вывод следующий

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\prj_debug_2019-08-15T11-08-36
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\prj_debug_2019-08-15T11-08-36
None
```

Почему последнее значение g.folder None?

get_folder() тоже всегда возвращает None.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: При выходе из контекста всё внутри flask.g уничтожается

Comment: Храните прямо внутри app например